# How to iterate on each record of a Model.stream waterline query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I need to do something like:

```
Lineup.stream({foo:"bar"}).exec(function(err,lineup){

  // Do something with each record
});
```

Lineup is a collection with over 18000 records so I think using `find` is not a good option. What's the correct way to do this? From docs I can't figure out how to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`.stream()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/stream) method returns a [node stream interface](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) ( a read stream ) that emits events as data is read. Your options here are either to [`.pipe()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) to something else that can take "stream" input, such as the response object of the server, or to attach an [event listener](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) to the events emitted from the stream. i.e:

**Piped to response**

```
Lineup.stream({foo:"bar"}).pipe(res);
```

**Setup event listeners**

```
var stream = Lineup.stream({foo:"bar"});

stream.on("data",function(data) {
    stream.pause();        // stop emitting events for a moment
    /*
     * Do things
     */
    stream.resume();       // resume events
});

stream.on("err",function(err) {
    // handle any errors that will throw in reading here
});
```

The `.pause()` and `.resume()` are quite inportant as otherwise things within the processing just keep responding to emitted events before that code is complete. While fine for small cases, this is not desirable for larger "streams" that the interface is meant to be used for.

Additionally, if you are calling any "asynchronous" actions inside the event handler like this, then you need to take care to `.resume()` within the callback or promise resolution , thus waiting for that "async" action to complete itself.

But look at the "node documentation" linked earlier for more in depth information on "stream".

P.S I believe the following syntax should also be supported if it suits your sensibilities better:

```
 var stream = Lineup.find({foo:"bar"}).stream();
```

Comment: Will `data` in `stream.on('data')` be every record?

Comment: @diegoaguilar Yes. The "stream" is implemented as a feed from server cursor, one record at a time.

Comment: I'm using Sails, I used `Model.find().stream()` and `Model.stream()` and didn't work ... Is this node mongo driver only?

Comment: @diegoaguilar The link is right at the front of the answer.